# Life MVC applications - IIS

Tags: iis, model-view-controller

I've a web application (MVC) that performs processes in different time intervals.
However, after a period of inactivity, the application "dies".
I guess that "kills" IIS.
What should I do that applications live permanently?

Is it possible that kills something else?

Answer (score 2):

Each web application is executed by an app pool. App pools have an idle time, when that time is reached, the app pool shoots down until there is another request. You could set the idle time to a higher value.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956

That say, it's a bad practice to have long running process in Asp.Net application. You should create a Windows Service for that.

Comment: thank you...Is there something else that could "kill" the application unless app pools ( session or something else)

Comment: Yes, if there are unhandled exceptions or excessive memory pressure, the app pool dies. But you better redesign your app to execute those long running process outside asp.net instead of trying to use it for a task that it wasn't designed to.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a quick solution or patch.
What is the Windows service that ping application? Is it possible something like that?

Comment: You could create a Windows task that request a page from your site at regular intervals, as a quick&dirty solution.

Comment: It's great if the request is sufficient. Tnx tnx tnx

Comment: @IvanaV A request will bring to life the app pool if it's down, so next user will wait less for respnse, but it wont help in recovering from exceptions.